# Android: Transferring TCP connection from 3G to WiFi

Tags: android, tcp, 3g

I'm creating an application for Android that uses TCP to download files. It's done, and working great, but I'm having a problem with people switching from a network to another while downloading files, because the download halts and eventually times out. Some devices even have a function that activates WiFi immediately when a suitable hotspot is found and disables the existing mobile data connection.

How to keep a TCP-based connection alive while switching networks? Is it even possible? I don't know much about networking, but I know that TCP connections are pinned to IPs and that mobile network and wifi interfaces on Android phones have different IPs. So, if the IP changes, is the existing connection complete unreachable by the other network?

Comment: I'm actually surprised that the changeover does not just work seamlessly - TCP is designed to handle multiple links that go up/down.  L2/L3 should, AFAIK, just use the other connection.  Perhaps android does not work, ie. it disables the 3G connections before the Wifi comes up.  That would be a bad plan:(

Answer (score 3):

Download the file in smaller chunks rather than as one complete download. If one chunk times out because the connection changes, you initiate the chunk again using the currently available connection type.

Comment: While a good idea in general, it might not work all the times. If downloading from e.g. a web-server, not all servers support starting downloading from a specific position in a file.

Comment: Only the OP would know this. We can only give suggestions to the problem he/she is experiencing based on the information we have. If the server does not support resumable downloads the only alternative is to restart the download.